# Explanation of a theorem in complex geometry

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, determinant

I'm currently trying to understand the following theorem written in the book "Complex Numbers from A to Z"(read from where it says "Theorem 3" to where it says "Problem 1"):
[First Page of Theorem + Proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNZtF.png)

[Second Page of Theorem + Proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vE4eM.png)

My issue is statement (4). I understand everything else, including how (5) could follow from (2), but I do not understand the significance of #4 at all, nor how it connects to (2) or (5).

I think what's confusing me is, first of all, how any sort of conclusion about the determinant expressed in (4) would follow from the fact that (z-a)/(b-a) is equal to its conjugate. Secondly, it seems to me that the determinant shown in (4) is the determinant of a 2x3 matrix, and correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't the determinant of a 2x3 matrix *always 0*? What makes this special?

If you need any further context, this all comes from the book "Complex Numbers from A to Z." You can find the PDF online; all this info begins on about page 76 of the pdf.

Comment: Statement (4) is the determinant of a $2\times 2$ determinant equaling $0$. The first row first column is $\,z-a.$

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!